# /usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity Error Installing elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, usb

I have a Innjoo Leapbook A100 and when I try to install elementary OS (try live and then install or install directly) The installer simply close or crashes. Once it showed an error saying "/usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity" crashed.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Leap A-100; Lubuntu installed

First download an alternate image of Lubun, it doesnt use ubiquity thing

Then, install it with rufus.

Forgive my lousy english ;)